# Theme settings to include different PHP files into template

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to include a template section into another template under conditions based on the themes settings.

**page.tpl.php**

```
<header>
    <?php
    $theme_header_style = theme_get_setting('header_style');//the value is 1
    $header_path = "header_tpl_".$theme_header_style.".php";
    include_once $header_path;//includes header_tpl_1.php
    ?>
    <h1><?php print $site_name; ?></h1><!--this works-->
</header>
```

**header_tpl_1.php**

```
<h1>this will show up</h1>
<h1><?php print $site_name; ?></h1><!--this will not work just an empty h1--> 
<p>this will show up on page.tpl.php as well</p>
```

I'm pulling in `header_style` from my themes settings and for this example the value is 1. The file it will include is being added, as the html from the file is displaying but any php in the file is being ignored. anything on page.tpl.php is working as expected its only the php content on included files like `header_tpl_1.php` that is not working.

**Update**

Now that I know using a PHP include doesn't work I would like to know how I could include the contents of the `header_tpl_1.php` into the template prior to Drupal rendering the page, as this clearly would be the solution. The end objective is being able to load different PHP files into `page.tpl.php` based on a value set in the themes settings. The code in my `header_tmp_1.php` was removed from `page.tpl.php` as working code and put into `header_tpl_1.php` so I know there are no errors in it, as it works if it's added directly into `page.tpl.php`. The problem is including content into a template. I need the content to be included prior to Drupal rendering the variables.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: i have files in my template directory "header_tpl_0.php", "header_top_1.php" and so on and depending on the selection made in the theme settings it will include that header section. each header section pulls in normal header data like site name, logo, breadcrumb, and so on. It works if its inside the page.tpl.php but not if its included.

Comment: It includes the file and shows the html but the php is not executed.

Comment: Templates are `eval`d, maybe a scope issue? This sort of decision should ideally be made in preprocess functions, then you wouldn't have an issue

Comment: Is there a tutorial for including sections of template into a tmp file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you cleared cache ? I usually include header.inc, but I try your code and it worked on my site.

[image: header code]

Comment: the file that you included did it try to print out drupal variables? I have cleared the cash multiple times. Its including the file. The html is showing up. the php drupal methods are not being executed.

Comment: for example if you put `<?php print $site_name; ?>` into your header_tpl_1.php file will it print out the site name?

Comment: If you need print variable on page template file, you should use hook [Hook preprocess page link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).

I print `<?php print $logo; ?>` on this header_tpl_1.php and it worked nomarly.

- Code  : [Imgur image link](http://i.imgur.com/POh2hnx.jpg)
-  Demo :   [Imgur Image link](http://i.imgur.com/wRivZBP.jpg)

Comment: are you including header_tpl_1.php into page.tmp.php using a php include

Comment: Yes, see  First Image on my answer. i use your code `include_once $header_path;` to include header_tpl_1.php to page.tpl.php.  If HTML is showing up, it mean you include header_tpl_1.php success. But your variable maybe don't have value. You should test by print this vars on page.tpl.php

Comment: If variable cannot print on page.tpl.php, it's mean this vars didn't declare on hook_preprocess_page function.

Comment: the vars that are not printing are on `header_tpl_1.php` not `page.tpl.php` the include is adding the html from `header_tpl_1.php` into `page.tpl.php` but is not executing the php on `header_tpl_1.php`

Comment: Please paste your code of your header_tpl_1.php, i will check it.

Comment: I did. My question is a simple demonstration of what is going on. The calls that are being made in the header_tpl_1.php where once part of my page.tpl.php at one time and work. There is nothing wrong with the code it just will not work when its included. Its something to do with how php includes files that is the problem.